# webpack is renaming my scss classes

Tags: webpack

I have taken webpack config from here:

```
https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example
```

1. For the production version, I made the suggested changes and now the
   loaders for less ,scss and css look like this

   ```
         { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')},
         { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=2&sourceMap!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
         { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true') }
   ```
2. I am loading stylesheets using require i.e

   require('../pathToSCSSSTylSheet')

CSS gets loaded just fine but scss classes are renames in the final stylesheet produced by webpack and so classes never get applied. How do I stop renaming of these scss classes?

I have taken `&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]` and tried keeping it too but the classes are renamed anyway

Answer (score 4):

You can import the styles like this

```
:global { 
  @import 'scss_path';
}
```

It will import styles as global styles, so you will get scss classes without being renamed.

Answer (score 2):

remove `modules` option,this enable CSS Modules.

see https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#user-content-css-modules for more details.

If you don't want to remove `modules` option, you can use like [this](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/components/InfoBar/InfoBar.js):

```
import styles from './app.scss';
export default class InfoBar extends Component{
  render(){
    const styles = require('./InfoBar.scss');
    return (
      <span className={styles.time}>10:00</span>
   );
 }
}
```