# Importing and retaining global css class names with postcss

Tags: css, rollup, postcss

I have `postcss` configured in my `rollup` project and is used for transforming `.css` files . This works for us and especially in our little `library` project. classes like `.name`, `address` are bundled into `name_[hash]` etc. by postcss. This is good and Ok for my local styles. However, I use another third party dependency that has it's own `css` classes and `styles`. Changing those classes end up affecting the styling. When I port

```
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css'
```

The above import and bundle the styles. However, The classes `.Codemirror` for example end up being bundled as `Codemirror_[hash]` . This changes by `postcss` breaks the styles by this dependency. Pleaee is there anyway I can import these files without changing the `classes` ? I read [webpack is renaming my scss classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439028/webpack-is-renaming-my-scss-classes) that I can import it like below.

```
:global { 
  @import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'
  @import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css'
}
```

The above however didn't work too. I also read that I can import the two inside the `render` function as `require` . This however, will be an issue in a library where the consumer doesn't have the `codemirror` dependency . Please how do I inject this `global` styles without breaking the class names ? Any help is appreciated .